# How to fetch Profile gid from hook_civicrm_post included in a Contribution Page?

Tags: profile, hooks

I am using profile object inside

```
function hook_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef){

}
```

How can I fetch the Profile gid from the above variables? or is there any way to implement it ?
I want to create a household on submission of a Profile A using custom fields and similarly create an Organization on submission of a Profile B using custom fields.
So I need a Profile ID which will distinguish between Profile A and Profile B using gid.

The $objectRef variable has the following structure for Profile

```
Array
    (
        [qfKey] => f6a85f995860db13425c24378f05c98d_9488
        [entryURL] => https://example.com/example-registration/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&
        [email-Primary] => check@gmail.com
        [first_name] => check
        [last_name] => gmail
        [phone-Primary-1] => 
        [street_address-Primary] => abc
        [supplemental_address_1-Primary] => a
        [city-Primary] => cci
        [postal_code-Primary] => 30200
        [country-Primary] => 1013
        [state_province-Primary] => 1640
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [custom_16] => Array
            (
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
            )

        [custom_17] => 
        [5] => 
        [custom_1] => Array
            (
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
            )

        [custom_18] => 
        [custom_19] => Partner check
        [payment_processor_id] => 0
        [priceSetId] => 8
        [price_12] => 40
        [selectProduct] => 
        [cms_create_account] => 1
        [cms_name] => familycheck
        [cms_pass] => test
        [cms_confirm_pass] => test
        [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 20971520
        [ip_address] => 192.51.248.26
        [amount] => 65
        [amount_level] => 
        [selectMembership] => 2
        [tax_amount] => 
        [currencyID] => AUD
        [is_pay_later] => 1
        [invoiceID] => 0c6d15e48854236861cdc16a4a8222e9
        [is_quick_config] => 1
        [email-5] => check@gmail.com
        [description] => Online Contribution: Family Registration
        [accountingCode] => 
        [addressee] => 1
        [email_greeting] => 1
        [postal_greeting] => 1
        [updateBlankLocInfo] => 
    )
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the context? On what you want to achieve? Probably the gid is in the objectRef

Comment: Hi @JaapJansma-CiviCooP I have updated the answer, the objectRef does not have it,kindly check it and let me know if your thoughts,Thanks!

Comment: does the objectId hold the id of the profile? If so then you could probably retrive it that way. Waht exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @JaapJansma-CiviCooP, I need to create a household using profile field on a contribution Page , but when I try to add a Profile of type Household it gives an error

Comment: $objectId gives profile id which is not gid for the profile

Comment: You have completly lost me. See my answer below how to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry @JaapJansma-CiviCooP to complicate it, but my question would be on how I can differentiate between 2 profiles in hook_civicrm_post? do we have any parameter which can help to check it out?

Comment: You can differentiate between the two profiles with the objectId parameter. That one gives you the ID of the profile

Comment: I am curious why is my answer below not sufficient? It does create a household when you add a household field to the profile

Comment: Hello Sir @JaapJansma-CiviCooP, I will mark your answer as correct, It was mistake that I did not add proper question, I was actually trying to add two fields
1) Household Name
2) Individual First Name (who would be member of that household)
When I try to add both Household name and Individual , it does not allow me to do so ,hence I moved to custom profiles,sorry again, you have been very helpful, but I was not able to put the detailed info across to you to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profiles directly to create an Household. When you add a field to a profile you have first select the entity, which could be contact, Individual, subtype of Individual, Household, Organization and others.

So there is no need to program this.

[image]